# Portatif ou portable ?

Tags: usage, synonymes, anglicismes

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=portatif%2C%20portable&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cportatif%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cportable%3B%2Cc0) que portable est bien plus courant que portatif. [Or](http://correspo.ccdmd.qc.ca/index.php/document/la-place-de-lamelioration-de-la-langue-dans-les-nouveaux-cours-de-litterature/portable-ou-portatif/)

> L'adjectif portable est souvent confondu avec portatif, de la même
>   famille. L'un et l'autre font partie du vocabulaire français ; encore
>   faut-il connaître la différence entre eux. Portable signifie « qu'on
>   peut porter, mais qui n'a pas été expressément conçu à cette fin ».
>
> Ex. : Il faut déménager ce gros ordinateur. Ex. : Croyez-vous qu'il
>   soit portable ? Portatif signifie « qui est conçu pour être facilement
>   transporté avec soi ».
>
> Ex. : Les ordinateurs portatifs coûtent souvent plus cher que les
>   ordinateurs de format régulier. Ex. : Ce macho avait amené son épouse
>   au restaurant ; malheureusement pour elle, il avait aussi son
>   téléphone portatif !

Je pense que ça c'est à cause de l'influence de l'anglais. Peut-on employer de nos jours portatif pour dire téléphone portatif ou ordinateur portatif ? Sera-t-on compris ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oui portable a été réintroduit (1939) en français comme synonyme de portatif sous l'influence de l'anglais (*portable*, lui-même [emprunté](https://www.etymonline.com/word/portable#etymonline_v_18491) au français) (DHLF), la différence étant le caractère empirique (portable) par opposition à la qualité inhérente et voulue (portatif) (DHLF). On peut dire également [ordinateur portatif](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8874365) ou [ordinateur portable](http://www.culture.fr/franceterme/result?francetermeSearchTerme=ordinateur%20portable&francetermeSearchDomaine=0&francetermeSearchSubmit=rechercher&action=search) ; l'article Wikipédia pour [*ordinateur portable*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinateur_portable) s'appuie sur des [vedettes surannées](http://www.gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8393157) de sources crédibles ou sur la nomenclature des vedettes plutôt que leur [contenu](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/portatif_portative/62687/difficulte). Une autre réponse choisit une page d'homonymie plutôt que l'article comme tel sur le sujet pour différencier le lexique avec le *téléphone* alors que l'[article](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%C3%A9l%C3%A9phone_mobile) présente les trois termes (*portable, mobile, cellulaire*) côte à côte : on lira plutôt des [notes](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%C3%A9l%C3%A9phone_mobile#cite_note-1) pour établir des différences entre les usages régionaux et on peut aussi jeter un coup d’œil sur un [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=t%C3%A9l%C3%A9phone+mobile%2Ct%C3%A9l%C3%A9phone+portable%2Ct%C3%A9l%C3%A9phone+cellulaire%2Ct%C3%A9l%C3%A9phone+portatif%2Cordinateur+portable%2Cordinateur+portatif&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ct%C3%A9l%C3%A9phone%20mobile%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ct%C3%A9l%C3%A9phone%20portable%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ct%C3%A9l%C3%A9phone%20cellulaire%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ct%C3%A9l%C3%A9phone%20portatif%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cordinateur%20portable%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cordinateur%20portatif%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ct%C3%A9l%C3%A9phone%20mobile%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ct%C3%A9l%C3%A9phone%20portable%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ct%C3%A9l%C3%A9phone%20cellulaire%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ct%C3%A9l%C3%A9phone%20portatif%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cordinateur%20portable%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cordinateur%20portatif%3B%2Cc0) (partiel). Il y a certainement concurrence entre *portatif* et *portable* dans les domaines de l'informatique et des télécommunications ; mais t*éléphone portable* est vraiment plus courant que de téléphone portatif au corpus du ngram ([Larousse en ligne](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/portatif_portative/62687/difficulte) en faisait état d'ailleurs).

---

Sans contexte on pense qu'on risque d'être davantage compris pour l'ordinateur que pour le téléphone mais c'est un peu théorique vu que si sur un bureau on a l'ordinateur et le téléphone on a tendance à pointer vers l'objet ou à indiquer le but recherché quand on demande de l'avoir (*prête-moi ton...* [on pointe] *je veux faire un appel* etc.) ; par ailleurs il y a convergence des fonctions des appareils etc. bof.

Comment: Even my local movie theater has responded to the convergence of functions about which you "bof" (rightfully so, imo), i.e., "Please silence your portable devices." RE "pointing" (& other contextual clues), I'm noticing more & more that (in English), "telephone" (or just "phone" for short)="cell/mobile/etc phone" and only needs modifying when one is NOT referring to cellular/mobile phones, as in "home phone" or "land-line [phone]." For elderly old me, "portable" phones were those land-line phones that weren't connected to their chargers/bases with tangled wires (aka cordless/Extendaphones)!

Answer (score 2):

Je comprendrai « téléphone portatif » ou « téléphone mobile » ou « mobile », cependant les gens disent « portable » ; cela est aussi un [ordinateur portable](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinateur_portable) ; plus rarement ils disent « [cellulaire](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellulaire) ». « Portatif » en isolation pourrait ne pas être compris.